# If $[G:H]=n$, then $g^{n!}\in H$ for all $g\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following question:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $H$ be a subgroup of finite index of $G$. Let $|G:H|=n$
> Then this holds: $g^{n!}\in H$ for all $g\in G$.
>
> Why is this true?

I think, that's not very difficult, but I have no idea at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the Pigeonhole principle?

Comment: Thank you for these nice solutions!

Comment: It seems you have asked many questions but have accepted answers to none of them. If you are satisfied with the answer of a question you have asked, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark below the up/down arrows. It lets other users know that this question has a good answer.

Comment: If $H$ is normal in $G$, we actually have $g^n \in H$ (see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545417).

Comment: (See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472672, if $H$ is normal in $G$).

Answer (score 17):

Let $G$ act on the left cosets of $H$ by left multiplication,
$$g: aH\longmapsto gaH.$$
This gives an action of $G$ on a set of $n$ elements, hence induces a homomorphism $G\to S_n$. In particular, for every $g\in G$, $g^{n!}$ must lie in the kernel, since $|S_n|=n!$. But the kernel is contained in $H$: if $g$ lies in the kernel, then $gaH = aH$ for all $a\in G$, hence in particular $gH=H$, so $g\in H$. Thus, for every $g\in G$, $g^{n!}\in H$.

Comment: One may observe that the $n!$ can be replaced by the exponent of $S_n$ (which is considerably lower than $n!$) and the proof still works.

Comment: @Andrea: It *may* be lower than $n!$ and usually is (except for small $n$). Of course, the above does even more, since we are showing that $g^{n!}\in \cap_{x\in G}xHx^{-1}$.

Comment: @AndreaMori, what is the exponent of $S_n$?

Comment: @lhf: See [the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A003418), sequence A003418.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, thanks. I knew that already but I had forgotten: $\exp S_n = \operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)$.

Comment: @Arturo- I need to check out some reasoning. Can we argue as follows: if $g\in H$, then $g^{t} \in H$ for any integer $n$, whence $g^{n!} \in H$; if $g \notin H$, then, since the index of $H$ is $n$, $g^{n}H = H$ and so $g^{n} \in H$, whence $g^{n!} \in H$ by closure under multiplication? If correct, this argument would do the job, but it wouldn't introduce $n!$ naturally, as your argument does.

Comment: @ChrisLeary: It is false that $H$ of index $n$ implies $g^nH=H$. For example, in $S_3$, $H=\{1,(1\;2)\}$ is of index $3$, but $(1\;3)^3H = (1\;3)H\neq H$. (The claim would be true if $H$ were *normal*, because then the order of $gH$ in $G/H$ would divide $[G:H]$, but it is false for arbitrary subgroups).

Comment: @ChrisLeary: You cannot do better than $\mathrm{lcm}(2,3,\ldots,n)$, I think: take $G=S_n$ and $H=\{(1\;2)\}$.

Comment: @Arturo - Thanks so much. I guess this is one of the occupational hazards of working in abelian groups for a living (mostly). I just buzzed over the fact that subgroups are not necessarily normal in general.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone wanted a nice name for the minimal number, it is basically the obvious guess, though I think it might be a little surprising that the obvious guess is actually right.

**Proposition:** If *G* is a group, and *H* is a subgroup of *G*, then the exponent of $G/\operatorname{Core}_G(H)$ is the smallest positive integer *n* such that for all *g* in *G*, $g^n \in H$.

*Proof:* Suppose *n* is a positive integer such that $g^n \in H$ for all *g* in *G*. Let *k* in *G*, then $(g^{k^{-1}})^n \in H$ as well. Conjugating by *k*, $g^n \in H^k$.  In particular, $g^n$ is contained in every conjugate of *H*, not just *H* itself.  Hence $g^n$ is contained in $\operatorname{Core}_G(H) = \displaystyle \bigcap_{g\in G}H^g$, the largest *G*-normal subgroup of *H*.  In particular, *n* is a multiple of the exponent of the group $G/\operatorname{Core}_G(H)$.  Conversely, the exponent *n* of the group $G/\operatorname{Core}_G(H)$ definitely satisfies $g^n \in \operatorname{Core}_G(H) \leq H$. $\qquad \square$

Equivalently, if *G* is a transitive permutation group, then the smallest positive integer *n* such that the *n*th power of every element of *G* fixes the first point is also the smallest positive integer *n* such that the *n*th power of every element of *G* fixes *every* point.

Answer (score 8):

Take $g\in G.$ Apply the pigeonhole principle to the $n+1$-tuple $g_0,\ldots,g_n,$ inductively defined by $g_0=e,$ and $g_{i+1}=g.g_i.$

You find $g_i$ and $g_j$ in the same left coset of $H$ in $G,$ for some $i,j=0,1,\ldots,n$ with $i<j.$

Consequently $g^{j-i}=g_jg_i^{-1}\in H,$ therefore a fortiori $g^{n!}\in H.$

Answer (score 2):

See also my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545417/if-gh-n-is-it-true-that-xn-in-h-for-all-x-in-g/546031#546031)

> **Proposition.** Let $H$ be a non-trivial subgroup of the finite group $G$, with $n = [G:H]$. Assume that $\gcd(|H|,n)=1$. Then the following are equivalent.
>
> (a) For all $g \in G$: $g^n \in H$.
>   (b) $H \unlhd G$.

Answer (score -6):

This is an easy question if you start by showing that $g^n \in H$. Consequently, $g$ raised to the power of any multiple of $n$ is also in H (since $[G:H] = n$). Just an idea.

Comment: This only works when $H$ is normal in $G$. Read the other proofs.