# H is a subgroup of a finite group G, and if |G| = m|H|, adapt the proof of Lagrange's Theorem to show that g^m! ∈ H for all g ∈ G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I'm finding this question particularly difficult to answer. Could someone help me, please?

Edit: I have seen the use of the notation ker which I know translates to kernel, in some solutions, but this notation is not used in my course on Group Theory. What is the alternative solution to this?

Armstrong question 11.11

Comment: Hint: Consider the cosets $H$, $Hg$, $Hg^2$, ...

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545417/if-gh-n-is-it-true-that-xn-in-h-for-all-x-in-g

Comment: But I wonder what the book intends by suggesting that we "adapt the proof of Lagrange's Theorem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the set of left cosets of $H$. Then $\phi: G \to \text{Sym}(X)$ given by $\phi(g)(aH)=(ga)H$ is a homomorphism. Therefore, by Lagrange's Theorem, $id = \phi(g)^{m!}= \phi(g^{m!})$ for all $g \in G$. In particular, $H=\phi(g^{m!})(H)=g^{m!}H$ and so $g^{m!} \in H$.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer fits the book's suggestion that we "adapt the proof of Lagrange's Theorem".

Comment: Yes, that must be what is meant by that condition.

Comment: I know this is a novice question to ask, but what is the definition of the notation Sym? That notation has never appeared in my textbook, so I don't really understand what is going on here.

Comment: @Goooie, $\text{Sym}(X)$ is the group of bijections (permutations) of $X$.