# Cyclic group associated with subgroup

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

I have a naive question on group theory, which I'm not familiar with in any detail.

Let $H<G$ be a subgroup of some group $G$. Let $g\in G$, $g\not\in H$, but $g^n\in H$ for some $n\geq 2$.
Does there exist a notion of a  cyclic subgroup generated by $g$, i.e. $\{g^k|k=0,\dots, n-1\}$, in which $g^n$ is identified with the identity?
The element $g$ is not necessarily a torsion element of $G$.

Comment: do you remember what is the meaning of being a torsion element?

Comment: You want $g$ be torsion or torsion free?

Comment: I'm interested in cases where $g$ is not a torsion element. @janmarqz A torsion element is an element $g$ such that $g^n=e$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, correct?

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you want to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019892/show-that-am-is-in-h-for-every-a-in-g?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde No I'm specifically interested in the case when $H$ is not a normal subgroup. Such elements appear in subgroups of the modular group $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, and I'm wondering if they can be characterised without knowing anything more about the specifics of $H$ and $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H$ is normal, we can speak of $g$ in the quotient group $G/H$ having order $n$.

Or, we can speak of $G$ acting by left-multiplication on the coset space $G/H$, giving us a homomorphism $G\to\mathrm{Perm}(G/H)$ (the kernel is the normal core of $H$). Then we can speak of $g$ in this image, and describe its cycles. One of its cycles is $(e~g~\cdots~g^{n-1})$, but other cycles may have different lengths. This is not the same as generating a cyclic subgroup of order $n$. We can *restrict* the action of $\langle g\rangle$ to the cycle $\langle g\rangle H$, in which case the image of the action is literally a group (generated by $g$'s image) of order $n$, but that is artificial.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not familiar with cycles, where does it appear?

Comment: In the context of permutations (every permutation has a "cycle type," or "cycle notation"), and more generally permutation group theory.