# If $[G:K] = m$, then prove that $g^m \in K$ for all $g \in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

> Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G.$ If $[G:K] = m$ then prove that $g^m \in K$ for all $g \in G$.

*Solution:* If $[G:K] = m$ then $|G/K| = m$. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of an element divides the order of the group. Therefore $(gK)^m = K$ for any coset $gK$. So for any $g \in G$, we have $(gK)^m = g^mK = K$, which means that $g^m \in K$. $\square$

---

I don't understand why we can make the claim that $(gK)^m = K$ for all cosets $gK$ because the order of an element divides the order of the group.

Comment: Do you assume $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$?

Comment: sorry I modified it

Comment: The order of an element $x$ divides an integer $n$ iff $x^n$ is the identity.

Comment: ...and the order of the element $gK\in G/K$ divides the order $[G:K]$ of the group $G/K$ (whose identity element is $K$).

Comment: Two people cooperating on completing an answer in the comment section today. That's not where answers should go.

Comment: @AnneBauval  so what you guys are saying is that in every single group, every single element to the power of the order of the group will give back the identity

Comment: that doesn't make intuitive sense

Comment: @user20194358 If $G$ is a finite group then by Lagrange's theorem the order of every element $g\in G$ divides $|G|$. It follows that $g^{|G|}=e$.

Comment: @Mark okok it makes sense. thank you

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573050/if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-g-of-finite-index-n-then-under-what-condition-gn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $K$ is normal in $G$, $G/K=\{gK|\forall g\in G\}$ is the quotient group (factor group), the order of this quotient group is $m$. Now, take an arbitray element $gK$ from this quotient group, we have $(gK)^m=K$. Note $K$ plays as the unit element in the quotient group (like $e$ plays as the unit element in $G$). Because $K$ is normal in $G$, which means $gK=Kg$, so we have $(gK)^m=g^mK^m=g^mK=K$, and this implies $g^m\in K.$

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP wants to know why $g^mK=K$. Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: "Note K plays as the unit element in the quotient group (like e plays as the unit element in G)." Does this answer it?

Comment: Ah, I see; sorry!

Comment: no worries. :-)