Does $g^p \in H ,\forall g\in G$ imply that $H \triangleleft G $?
I know that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with index $m$ ,then $g^m \in H, \forall g\in G$. But is the converse true in this case when m is a prime $p$?
Let $G$ be a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with index $p$. If $g^p \in H , \forall g\in G$ then $H \triangleleft G$

I found the answer to my question in this paper On Subgroups of Prime Index by
T. Y. Lam

I missed the "index $p$" clause.

@ArturoMagidin Not a problem

Problem statement questions are not supported on this site. Please check out How to ask a good question. Notice that you didn't include your own progress of an attempt to solve this problem, and any examples.

@MartinBrandenburg My attempts were either wrong or nonsense. Should I write them?

It's important to identify whether or not it's a dupe.   This site should be a compendium.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573050/if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-g-of-finite-index-n-then-under-what-condition-gn

Yes. Consider the action of $G$ by multiplication on the (left or right, whichever you prefer) cosets of $H$ in $G$. This action is transitive, and so the image of the action has order divisible by $p$.
I claim that this image has order exactly $p$, which implies that the action is regular and $H$ is normal in $G$. If not, then the stabilizers in the action are non-trivial. Since the action is transitive, we can choose $g$ in such a stabilizer that does not fix the coset $H$. So the cycle of $g$ on the coset $H$ has order $m$ with $1 < m < p$, and since $p$ is prime, $m$ does not divide $p$, so $g^p$ does not fix $H$. That is, $g^p \not\in H$, contrary to assumption.
I expect there is a more elegant way of writing that proof!

It might not be apparent, but I think that this proof and the proof supplied by Deif are essentially equivalent.

Let $h\in H$ and suppose that $h\not\in\text{Core}_G(H)$. If $g\in G$ then $(h^g)^p=(h^p)^g\in H$ and hence $h^p\in\text{Core}_G(H)$. By Cayley's theorem $|G/\text{Core}_G(H)|$ divides $p!$, and since $|G:H|=p$ it follows that $|H:\text{Core}_G(H)|$ divides $(p-1)!$. As $\text{Core}_G(H)\unlhd H$ and $o(h\text{Core}_G(H))=p$, by Lagrange's theorem we deduce that $p$ divides the order of $H/\text{Core}_G(H)$, which is not possible. Therefore $h\in\text{Core}_G(H)$ and $H\unlhd G$.
